# How to install Ubuntu 15.10 to a new SSD and create an easy dual boot menu?

Tags: dual-boot, ssd

My computer has an HDD which has Windows 10 on the `C:\` partition and there are two other logical partitions which are used by the whole family. I am sure the disk has an MBR partition system and my computer supports UEFI boot.

I want to buy a new SSD (around 120 GB), and want to install Ubuntu 15.10 on it. I need the boot menu to be easy because my wife uses Windows 10.

Any one know the complete installation steps?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: If you install Ubuntu in UEFI mode, then the only way to dual boot is from UEFI boot menu or one time boot key like f10 or f12. Grub can only boot systems installed in same boot mode. I might use gpt partitioning on SSD and add both a FAT32 300MB to 500MB for ESP - efi system partition for future UEFI boot, and a 1 or 2MB unformatted partition for BIOS boot.Then you can install in either BIOS and boot from grub both systems or convert Ubuntu later to UEFI without repartitioning or reinstalling. Best to disconnect Windows drive as grub will default to install to sda.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi) but I think there is a little difference, You are installing to different drives.

- Create UEFI ubuntu format media and install to SSD by following the link above. Don't touch anything on your HDD, Grub2 automatically takes priority on bios, it automatically founds other bootable systems on your pc's all drives. If it doesn't, you can find manually after installation.

Or You can set Windows Boot Manager to first boot option on bios, other users can easily start Windows, You can use boot options to start Ubuntu.